# why char array cant be copied like this charArray="some string";

Tags: c++, c, string

Why do we need to use `strcpy()` for copying a string into a char array?

I have wasted my 2 hours in this.It has not shown me any error but the output was not as I expected and I struggled 2 hours to find out the error.

It was just displaying a garbage char.

when I use `strcpy()` it works fine.

Comment: why not use `std::string`, and leave the worries behind

Comment: Yes I used std::string but my project have some legacy c code and I again have to convert this string to char.

Comment: You need a "C-string"? That's what `std::string::c_str()` is for.

Comment: yes for converting it to c char array one need to use c_str(); but my question is why we cant just copy the string using = operator.

Comment: This has got to be a dupe.

Comment: @NeilKirk - And because "char[]" is largely a fiction in C.

Comment: For the string case use `std::string`, but in general C++11` `std::array  was one of the greatest improvements of the language. Value semantics for arrays, not that "I decay to a pointer whenever I can"

Answer (score 2):

Another Interpretation of the answers is that char array is a basic type, not a class which `operator =` is overridden.

As mentioned by @StianV.Svendenborg that assigning a char array to another means assigning its address to another char pointer variable.

char array allocation such as;

```
char test[4]={1,2,3,4};
```

will result with an allocation of 4 bytes (each for a *char* value).

In expressions such as arithmetic will result of `test` to behave like pointer.For example `test+1` will point the address of second element and `*(test+1) == 2` will be true and
`print("%p",test)` will print the address of the first element in your array.

If you use the class `std::string` and `operator=`, function will go through all these allocated fields and copy them without your consideration.

Comment: I was trying to explain the behavior.

Comment: You don't need to state false things as if they are facts in order to explain the behavior.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley You are right. Is this form correct? Or I should delete the answer?

Comment: It's very slightly better, I guess. It's still a bit misleading though. `test` does not always behave as a pointer. For example, when taking its address or its size, or binding a reference to it. It would be better to say that in some expressions, an array is converted to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley updated with your feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Long answer:

Once you have declared any array in C++, whether that is an `int, char or MyClass` array any use of the name of that array is essentially the same as using a pointer to the first element in the array. This becomes dreadfully obvious as soon as the array is allocated dynamically, but is also the case for statically allocated arrays.

That means that the following code:

```
char arr[] = "Lorum ipsum";
```

Means:

Allocate enough room for 12 characters on the stack, and let arr behave as a pointer to the first character, this pointer is const (i.e. what is points to cannot be changed.)

Thus if you try to write:

```
const char * arr2 = "hello";
arr = arr2; // Error
```

What you are really asking is: Change `arr`, which behaves like a pointer that cannot be changed, to now point to the first character in this constant string. This is not allowed.

That being said, if you instead use a pointer to constant strings, you can use the syntax described:

```
const char * cstr1 = "Hello";
const char * cstr2 = "Bye";
cstr1 = cstr2;          // All is good, you are only changing which 
                        // c-string in the global data you are pointing to.
```

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer :
This is because arrays are allocated memory statically and you cannot reinitialize them.
Size of the array is fixed.
Instead you can use `std::string`.

Although, you can use a `char*` pointer like this.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:
For efficiency. For people who don't want the array to be copied.

When you use raw pointers, you need consider all these details such as memery management, copy behaviour etc, to achieve your own performance requirement. Other wise you can use `std::string`, which was designed to satisfy most normal case.

Answer (score 0):

So called C-strings originated from C language, that does not have high-level language functionality for string handling. There are two different concepts in here that you need to understand:

- string literals like `"abc"`, `""`, `"my string literal"`
- string variables

The first ones are **nonmodifable** (modyfing them is UB) arrays of type `char[n]`, where `n` is number of actual characters plus *null character* `'\0'`, which repesents end of string and have to be always present. You can access its individual elements using array subscipting operator directly e.g. `"abc"[1]` results into `'b'` character.

The second ones are programmer-declared arrays, that can hold C-string. For example:

```
#define STR_LEN 60

char str[STR_LEN+1] = "abc";
```

Don't confuse array initializer with `"abc"` string literal, the same are **not** the same things. Actually such initiliazer (for this array size) is equivalent to:

```
char str[STR_LEN+1] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
```

To handle string literals you need `char` pointer, not `char` array:

```
char *p_str = "abc" /* "abc" is string literal */
```

After  `char` array is declared you can't assign string literal to it directly, e.g.:

```
str = "def"; /* wrong, str is array, not pointer (not l-value) */
```

The only way to assign new string to array (string variable) is modify its elements, e.g.:

```
str[0] = 'd';
str[1] = 'e';
str[2] = 'f';
str[3] = '\0'; /* very important */
```

Instead of assigning individual characters, you can write a function to do it for you, e.g.:

```
char *my_strcpy(char dst[], const char *src)
{
    while ((*dst++ = *src++)) /* copying idiom */
        ;  
    return dst;
}
```

Example calls:

```
my_strcpy(str, "def");
my_strcpy(str, p_str);
```

Instead of writing you own function you can just use `strcpy` (or little safer `strncpy`) to do it for you. End of story.